# Inject data from array to cloned form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, inject

MySQL Return this multidimensionnal array with PHP

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
              [id] => 1 
              [name] => Alpha 
              [surname] => Martin 
              ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
              [id] => 2 
              [name] => Beta 
              [surnname] => Phlip 
             ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
              [id] => 3 
              [name] => Gamma 
              [surname] => Maurice 
            ) 
         )
```

I have a form with 3 clones (plugin SheepIt)

```
<form id="donnees" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="saisie_di_submitted.php">
   <div id="personne_cloning_template0" class="row-fluid sheepit-form" idtemplate="personne_cloning_template">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_0_ename" name="name[0]" value="">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_0_esurname" name="surname[0]" value="">                                                            
   </div>
   <div id="personne_cloning_template1" class="row-fluid sheepit-form" idtemplate="personne_cloning_template">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_1_ename" name="name[1]">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_1_esurname" name="surname[1]" >
   </div>
   <div id="personne_cloning_template2" class="row-fluid sheepit-form" idtemplate="personne_cloning_template">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_2_ename" name="name[2]">
      <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_2_esurname" name="surname[2]" >
   </div>
</form>
```

I wanted to inject the data from array to the form using jquery b ut i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I think I have to do a loop with data and inject thme to the form with something like personne_cloning_#row_number-1#_xxxxx but it seems difficult

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use jQuery for filling the form. I would rather use a loop in PHP.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<div id="personne_cloning_template' . $current. '" ... >';
    echo '<input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="personne_cloning_'. $row['id'] .'_ename" name="'.$row['name'].'">';
    // ... more html to add here
}
```

Comment: I use the jquery plugin SheepIt! to clone part of my form. When I clik on a button, the part of form is cloned [number of row] times. Now i would like to inject the data.